# Need help finding a tactics database with motifs

Tags: engines, computer-chess, database

I am trying to make a neural network which could determine what chess tactic is present in a position. For this, I need to have a database of chess tactics labelled with correct motifs.

A [similar question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8249/where-can-i-find-databases-of-tactical-problems-categorized-and-ranked-by-diffi) was asked a few years ago, but it is not particularly useful. Is there any website which has such database?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find databases of tactical problems, categorized and ranked by difficulty?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8249/where-can-i-find-databases-of-tactical-problems-categorized-and-ranked-by-diffi)

Answer (score 1):

Try the chess.com website. They have plenty of resources available. They also have a fully trained neural net which evaluated and scores your games with the aim to improve the player and facilitate their learning process.